# read all file names and a float in the files, list them sorted by float

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have pdb files in a directory, and in each of them there is a line written "TOTAL_ENERGY: somenumber" .i want to extract those energy values and the file names and make a text file listing them sorted by the energy values. i get different errors when i run it in different computers now im pretty confused. would be nice if someone can tell me how to write it correctly.

the energy value is written like this:

`TOTAL_ENERGY: -94.45499999999998`

And my code is like this so far.

````
import os 
import sys

#open and read each file in the path, if "TOTAL_ENERGY:" is written in a line extract 
#the total energy value, which is seperated by space, and in a txt file make a list
#of the file names and the energy value next to it. sort the list by the energy value

filename= os.listdir("/path/to/files/")
# print(file_list)
filename_and_energy=[]
text_file =  open('list_pdbs_energies.txt' , 'w')
for f in filename:
    with open(f, 'r') as text:
        lines=text.readlines()
        for l in lines:
            if 'TOTAL_ENERGY:' in l:
                cols =l.split()
                energy = float(cols[1][:-1])
                filename_and_energy.append((f, energy))
filename_and_energy.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])
text_file.write(filename_and_energy) ```



Thanks a bunch!
````

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be **cols[1].strip()** instead of **cols[1][:-1]** because the **split** method will split by space which will result in **["TOTAL_ENERGY:", "-94.45499999999998"]**

Also, you may want to add at the end **text_file.close()** to make sure that your file gets closed as it should be.

Comment: Alexandru, i tried now like that, i have error:   File "myscript.py", line 15, in <module>
    with open(f, 'r') as text:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:

Comment: Hello. This means that the file has not been found. The thing is that you need to concatenate the file name to the path you have **/path/to/files/** because os.listdir just return the relative path (file name) instead of the full path. Try like this: **with open("{}/{}".format("/path/to/files", f), 'r') as text**

Comment: Alexandru, Thank u!! i changed the line "with open(f, 'r') as text:" to "with open("{}/{}".format("/path/to/files", f), 'r') as text:" then i had the error text_file.write(filename_and_energy)
TypeError: write() argument must be str, not list, then i changed "text_file.write(filename_and_energy)" to "text_file.write(str(filename_and_energy))" now it is printing but not writing in a file and not giving any error o_0 i even created a text file in the directory to see if it is writing in it but no. why could that be??

Comment: You may try this: **for e in filename_and_energy: text_file.write("{}\n".format(e))**. If you do not want paranthesis to file: **for e in filename_and_energy: text_file.write("{} {}\n".format(e[0], e[1]))**